# Is the sentence below grammatically correct? Is it comprehensible?

Tags: grammaticality, complex-sentences, comprehension

*out of context:*
Gray had already provided a survey in 1995 amongst 2518 SMEs, with the result of 52% of the entrepreneurs having claimed that independence meant being bosses to ourselves or making a decision solely on our own.

Comment: Hi LillaK, welcome to English Language & Usage. Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. For further guidance, see [ask], and I can also recommend the **[Tour]** of this site. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it grammatically correct?*

Yes, however, the comma after "SMEs" indicates the last two thirds of the sentence are an "aside".

*Is it comprehensible?*

Yes, but I'd shorten it to:

Gray had already surveyed 2518 SMEs in 1995. 52% of the surveys showed that entrepreneurs defined independence as "being bosses to ourselves" or "making a decision solely on my own".